# C6001 on using the address of uninitialized value. Why?

Tags: c++, c, initialization, compiler-warnings

This here is my C++ code:

```
void somefn(char* string){
    char *current, *next;
    current = strtok_s(string, "a", &next);  // next is unitialized -> C6001 in VS 2020
}

int main(){
    char buf[] = "foobar";
    return 0;
}
```

which is deemed warning-worthy by a certain compiler with certain flags (should not matter, I believe).

The only questions are:

1. Does this lead to an undefined behavior? I currently believe that an address of an uninitialized variable is a compile-time constant.
2. Can this be for any reason considered bad practice? Why?

EDIT: Promised screenshot
[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225191/discussion-on-question-by-captain-trojan-c6001-on-using-the-address-of-uninitial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [reference documentation for `strtok_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) shows that the above code is perfectly valid *assuming that `string` is not a NULL pointer*. Whether "an address of an uninitialized variable is a compile-time constant" is completely irrelevant and doesn't have anything to do with the diagnostic. The compiler thinks you are using uninitialized memory.

However the 4th parameter to `strtok_s`, as per documentation, needs to have the pointed-to pointer initialized (by an earlier call to `strtok_s`) only if the first parameter is `NULL`.

The compiler is being rather picky, it seems. It looks like the compiler cannot prove to itself that `string` will never be `NULL` here, so it's complaining about this.

But, if you never call `strtok_s` here with a `NULL` pointer here then there's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: The unitialized value warning is not related to `string`, but to `next`. The compiler does not care about `string` whatsoever, it complains that I'm using `next` (actually, the address of `next`) without initializing it.

Comment: That is absolutely correct, and that's exactly what I wrote. But you're missing the bigger picture: `strtok_s` uses `next` only when `string` is `NULL`, but the compiler does not appear to know that, and it thinks that `next` is always used, as I explained.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: “The compiler does not care about `string` whatsoever”: That is false. The compiler cares that `string` might be a null pointer, and this would result in `next` being used uninitialized.

Comment: @EricPostpischil How exactly is `next` used unitialized? `next` is never used in my opinion. If `string == NULL`, then `strtok_s` believes this is a consequent call and should, IMHO, process its current token (which is NOT `next`) and assign something to `next` by referencing the passed argument. (something like `*restrict_ptr = this_and_that`, but it should never use `*restrict_ptr` itself).

Comment: @EricPostpischil IMO the compiler is overly cautious by issuing this warning on perfectly correct code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: You have the wrong link for `strtok_s`. OP is not using the C/C++ standard `strtok_s` (with four parameters) but is using [Microsoft’s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-s-strtok-s-l-wcstok-s-wcstok-s-l-mbstok-s-mbstok-s-l?view=msvc-160) (with three parameters).

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: The [documentation for `strtok_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-s-strtok-s-l-wcstok-s-wcstok-s-l-mbstok-s-mbstok-s-l?view=msvc-160) says the third parameter, which it calls `context` and you call `next`, is “Used to store position information between calls to the function.” The Remarks expand upon this: When you call `strtok_s` with null pointer for the first argument, it uses the third argument to know where to continue. Unlike `strtok`, it does not maintain internal state.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: So, the compiler here is “thinking”: It does not know whether `string` is null or not. And, if `string` is null, then `next` must be initialized. Since it is not initialized, the compiler warns you about this possibility. This is an overly aggressive warning; nobody is saying it is good behavior by the compiler. But that is the explanation for it.